# How to exit a javascript function inside itself after an "if"?

Tags: javascript

I´m creating a game and I've got stuck with a counter in a function.
I want the function to loop five times and then if my element "nocolnum" has a value of 5, i need the function to exit or break.
here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="opt1"></span>
        <span id="nocolnum">0</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my js:

```
function func(num) {
    num = num + 1;
    var opt = document.getElementById('opt1');
    opt.innerHTML= num + "%" ;
    var move = setTimeout("func("+num+")",15);
    var nocolnum = document.getElementById('nocolnum');

    if(num == 100){
        nocolnum.innerHTML++;
        clearTimeout(move);
    }

    if (nocolnum == 5) {
        // I dont know what to put here
        // to break out
        // a break, return or something??
    }

    var one = 0;
    func(one);
}
```

Comment: `return false;` automatically breaks off any sequence. (cheers Pugazh!)

Comment: return will stop execution of any function.

Comment: if `func` is called with value `101` or greater it will blow the stack.

Comment: @Roberrrt : It's `return false;`. Please edit your comment!

Comment: @Pugazh oops, done so, cheers!

Comment: You do realise execution continues when it hits your `setTimeout` - right? It does not halt execution of the current function!

Comment: And I think therein lies your problem - you're trying to exit out of a function called from a `setTimeout`. just `return` or `return false` will not do that. Can you describe what your function is trying to do, and there is a way to rewrite it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (nocolnum == 5) {
 // I dont know what to put here
 // to break out
 // a break, return or something??
 return false;

}
```

Comment: It seem each time you passing 0 count   var one = 0;  func(one);

Answer (score -1):

If you want to break function you can simlpy return

```
if (nocolnum == 5) {
    return true;
}
```

or

```
if (nocolnum == 5) {
    return false;
}
```